# Get the sum and product of integres defined in a tree

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming, expression-trees

I have a little problem understanding how to to the following in Haskell:

Lets say I have a statement similar to this ones:

- a * (b + c)
- a + (b * c)
- a + (b * ( c + d))
- a * (b + ( c * d))
- etc. etc.

I want to express these statements in a tree and evaluate the result of each, for starters I defined the following data structure:

```
data statement = Number Int 
               | Product statement statement 
               | Sum statement statement
               deriving (Eq, Show)
```

For an example Tree to work with, I used the following function:

```
a :: statement
a = Product (Number 2) (Sum (Number 5) (Number 1))
```

Now I want to build a function treeResult which gives me the result of my statement defined, but I don't know how to approach this problem. The integer returned for the above statement should be 12.

My first guess was to write a function that takes "statement" as a parameter and returns an int, for starters only with simple statements.

```
treeResult :: statement -> Int
treeResult (Number a) = a
treeResult (Product (Number a) (Number b)) = a*b
treeResult (Sum (Number a) (Number b)) = a+b
```

Now I know that I need something that works recursive but I don't know how to write it in haskell, can someone help me out here, please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off: `statement` needs to be capitalized since it's not a type variable. But that's the least important thing.

```
treeResult :: Statement -> Int
treeResult (Number x) = x
```

Obviously correct so far. We're matching the `Number` constructor, extract the `Int` and return that - well-typed and does what it should.

```
treeResult (Product (Number a) (Number b)) = a*b
treeResult (Sum (Number a) (Number b)) = a+b
```

This is well-typed, but it is not general enough. In this pattern, you are restricting the fields of `Product` and `Sum` to `Number`s, but in fact they can be any `Statement`. So you instead need to define the `Product`/`Sum`:

```
treeResult (Product a b) = ...
treeResult (Sum a b) = ...
```

But we can't just add/multiply the two `Statements`. `(+)` and `(*)` are not defined for them (we're kind of doing that right now). When one operand is a `Product`, how do we get its value as an `Int`? By evaluating it. **`Statement` is recursive, so we need recursion to evaluate it.** Thus, the function becomes

```
treeResult (Product a b) = (treeResult a) * (treeResult b)
treeResult (Sum a b) = (treeResult a) + (treeResult b)
```

Comment: Thats very detailed, this will help anyone who stumbles across the same problem. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 4):

```
treeResult (Sum statement1 statement2) = treeResult statement1 + treeResult statement2
```

Similar for Product. This is simply recognizing

- result of (a + b) == result of a + result of b

(BTW, the data type should be called `Statement` with an uppercase S.

```
data Statement = Number Int | Product Statement Statement | Sum Statement Statement
                 deriving (Eq, Show)
```

)

Comment: That's simply wrong. (Edit: Okay, now it's correct - but I still won't upvote, as it lacks any explanation)

Comment: I never would have thought it's that simple. Thank you very much for your help :)